# Cannot use namespace NavController as a type

Tags: angular, ionic2

i am beginner for hybrid application development and i am trying to build hybrid app using ionic-2 and Angular but when run my code its showing below error **[ts] Cannot use namespace 'NavController' as a type.**

can some on help me please how can i resolve my problem

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { DetailsPage } from '../details/details';
import {  DataAccess } from '../../providers/data-access';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  private dinosaurs: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private dataAccess: DataAccess) {
    this.dinosaurs = this.dataAccess
      .getDinosaurs();
  }

  goToDetails(dino){
    this.navCtrl.push( DetailsPage, {
      selectedDino: dino
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: you mention ionic 2.. assuming there is no lazy loading..can you include the app.module.ts in the question?

Comment: Also can you add a screenshot and not a phone cam snap?

Comment: yes i run the app in browser

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

 import { Nav } from 'ionic-angular';

    export class HomePage
    { 
      @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;


    constructor(){
    }

        //...........//



    function(){
       this.nav.push(yourPage)
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to re-install the project?

```
npm install
```

or

```
npm update
```